# 'The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured' - in Eclipse, working fine with Android Studio

Tags: android, adb, eclipse-adt

I have searched the same query but got the answer that I should restart Eclipse, but that trick is not working for me. I have also update with latest update of sdk. things are working perfectly in Android studio. But when I am open Eclipse it throws following error

```
[2017-04-27 12:14:08 - CRM] ------------------------------
[2017-04-27 12:14:08 - CRM] Android Launch!
[2017-04-27 12:14:08 - CRM] The connection to adb is down, and a 
severe error has occured.
[2017-04-27 12:14:08 - CRM] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2017-04-27 12:14:08 - CRM] Please ensure that adb is correctly 
located at 'F:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

Should I use different SDK for both. but it is space consuming task.

Also I am getting the following message when I run apk

```
`[2017-04-27 12:27:56 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: F:\SDK\tools\traceview.bat'
```

Comment: try adding the path to SDK tools and platform tools in your classpath from Environment Variables. Then restart Eclipse

Comment: @WilliamCross not wokred

Comment: I'm not sure then. does the file exist at F:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe ?

Comment: yes it is there

Comment: I would say in these cases usually the best bet is to start over from the beginning (as far as setting up your environment goes). Try following these steps for setting up Eclipse with the Android SDK and let me know if it helps :-). http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Setup-Eclipse-for-Android-App-Development/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My Case I used differnt SDk for eclipse and android studio works for me.

download SDk for eclipse from 
download sdk